# If $E,F \subseteq B$, then $f^{-1}(E \cup F) = f^{-1}(E) \cup f^{-1}(F)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am new to set theory, I understand here that we must show that both sides are subsets of each other. How do I develop a proof for the inverse of the function? I am learning set theory for a real analysis class. I understand this is quite a basic question, but if you can show me at least one side, I would appreciate it.

If $E,F \subseteq B$, then $f^{-1}(E \cup F) = f^{-1}(E) \cup f^{-1}(F)$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the set $f^{-1}(A)$? Careful - it is not the inverse function of $f$. The inverse of $f$ may not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f:A\rightarrow B$ (just to give the domain a name), for $E\subseteq B,$ $f^{-1}(E):=\{x\in A: f(x)\in E\}.$ So $f^{-1}(E\cup F)=\{x\in A: f(x)\in E\cup F\}.$ $f^{-1}(E)\cup f^{-1}(F)=\{x\in A: f(x)\in E\}\cup \{x\in A: f(x)\in F\}.$ Using these descriptions of the sets, and the definition of union, you should be able to prove the equality.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the $f$ preimage for $B$ exists, then the preimage of $E\cup F$ consists of all elements in the preimage for $B$ who map into $E\cup F$.
$$f^{-1}(E\cup F) ~{= \{x\in f^{-1}(B): f(x)\in E\cup F\} \\ ~\vdots~\\ = f^{-1}(E)\cup f^{-1}(F) }$$

Answer (score 0):

x in $f^{-1}(E \cup F)$ iff f(x) in E union F

iff f(x) in E or f(x) in F iff x in $f^{-1}(E) \cup f^{-1}(F)$.